# .Net equivalent of Swift map and reduce

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin

I got this operation:

```
let lines = (0..<linesCount).map({ _ in "\n" }).reduce("", +)
```

`lineCount` is an integer.

How can I convert this code to C#?

I have written something with `Enumerable.Range(1, linesCount)` and `.Select(...)` linked to `.Aggregate(...)` but I don't know what to put in (...) to get the exact same result as the Swift line.

Comment: What is expected output? Something like this "\n\n\n\n"?

Comment: `let lines = (0..<linesCount).map({ _ in "\n" }).reduce("", +)` is Swift, not Objective-C (which could be better said as `let lines = String(repeating: "\n", count: linesCount)`).

Comment: I guess you need just `new string('\n', linesCount)`

Comment: "the exact same result as the Objective-C line." That's Swift, not Objective-C. What is your question, translate it as such, or understanding what it does? Because map/reduce can be translated into for loop usually. So how do you want to mimick it in Xamarin? As close as possible to the Swift version, or just the logic?

Comment: thanks for your comments, it was a strange notation for me, but you explained it well so I now understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
var linesCount = 4;
var lines = Enumerable
    .Range(1, linesCount)
    .Select(i => "\n")
    .Aggregate((c, n) => $"{c}{n}");
```

However if you only need to create a string of single char that repeated several times you can use `string` constructor:

```
var lines = new string('\n', linesCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

[MapReduce in C#](https://www.justinshield.com/2011/06/mapreduce-in-c/)

Map in C#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var testList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
   var mapList = Map<int, int>(x => x + 2, testList);

   mapList.ToList<int>().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i + " "));
   Console.WriteLine();
   Console.ReadKey();
}

static IEnumerable<TResult> Map<T, TResult>(Func<T,TResult> func, 
IEnumerable<T> list)
{     
    foreach (var i in list)
       yield return func(i);
}
```

Reduce in C#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var testList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; 
   Console.WriteLine(Reduce<int, int>((x, y) => x + y, testList, 0));
   Console.ReadKey();
}

static T Reduce<T, U>(Func<U, T, T> func, IEnumerable<U> list, T acc)
{
   foreach (var i in list)
       acc = func(i, acc);

   return acc;
}
```